# what's the way to handle an if-else condition is dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using dialog flow to make a chat bot, but gets stuck.
I have an if-else condition which consists of 14-15 question.
How to handle condition type of question in dialog flow. until now, maybe fulfillment works, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details. Give an example of such question.

You don't need to use filfillments, you can solve it with input/output contexts.

```
// some example intents
study.start (output-context: study.yes & study.no)
study.no    (input-context: study.no)
study.yes   (input-context: study.yes, output-context: study.howlong.good & 
study.howlong.bad)

> Did you study for the test? No -> You need to study!
> Did you study for the test? Yes -> For how long? 
> For how long? 1 hour -> Study more!
> For how long? 5 hours -> Good!
```

You simply write example phrases which will match given the active contexts. Remember to only set a lifespan of 1 for your output contexts.